# can't get attribute function when running multiple processes

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing

I wanted to compare the speed when using multiprocessing and a normal linear function.

My code looks like this

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import time
from faker import Faker

num_rows = 1000000

items = [
    ['Column_1', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_2', Faker(), "random_element", {"elements": ["Kayden", "Franklin", "Gabriel", "Vincent"]}],
    ['Column_3', Faker(), "random_element", {"elements": ["Miller", "Ward", "Edwards", "Parry"]}],
    ['Column_4', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_5', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_6', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_7', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_8', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_9', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_10', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_11', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_12', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_13', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_14', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_15', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_16', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_17', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_18', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_19', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_20', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_21', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_22', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
    ['Column_23', Faker(), "pyint", {}],
]

def concurrent():
    with Manager() as dict_manager:
        data_frame = dict_manager.dict()

        global faker_function
        def faker_function(params):
            items = []
            for _ in range(0, num_rows - 1):
                items.append(getattr(params[1], params[2])(**params[3]))
            data_frame[params[0]] = items

        curr_time = time.time()
        with Pool(10) as p:
            p.map(faker_function, items)
        elapsed = time.time() - curr_time

        print('Concurrent', elapsed)
        print('Dict size', len(data_frame))

def linear():
    data_frame = {}

    def faker_function(params):
        items = []
        for _ in range(0, num_rows - 1):
            items.append(getattr(params[1], params[2])(**params[3]))
        data_frame[params[0]] = items

    curr_time = time.time()
    for item in items:
        faker_function(item)
    elapsed = time.time() - curr_time

    print('Linear time', elapsed)
    print('Dict size', len(data_frame))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    concurrent()

    linear()
```

Both functions `linear` and `concurrect` supposed to generate some data and write it into a dictionary (for multiprocessing I am using `Manager` object).

I have made the inner function - `faker_function` - into `global`.

But when I am running the app I get this error from the processes

```
Can't get attribute 'faker_function' on <module '__mp_main__'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Just make `faker_function` a top level function. On the other threads, this file will be read, but `concurrent()` won't be called.  So `faker_function` won't be defined.

Comment: but I am not sure how to integrate `manager` with `faker_function` if I were to make it into a global function - I wanted to use a context manager for `Manager` but in that case I will have to manually close using `close()`

Comment: I should also add that in this case, the concurrent version will be a lot slower.  It only. makes sense to use concurrency if the work done by each thread is more than the work of creating the thread, sending arguments to the thread, and receiving the results back.  In this case, so little work is done by thread that the answer is almost certainly no.

Comment: the thing is that without context manager (without writing to a second thread), with multithreading it was like 10 times faster. I just wanted to write results into a single structure (to imitate the real flow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me back up and say this is absolutely the wrong way to use multiprocessing for two reasons.

#1) Multiprocessing only makes sense when you each thread is doing a lot of work.  That work has to be more than the work of setting up the thread, sending arguments to the thread, and receiving the arguments back.  In this toy piece of code, this is almost certainly not the case.

#2) Having multiple threads all modify a single global data structure is a bad idea.  You can get it to work, but it's extremely slow and error prone.  What you want is for each thread to return a value or values, and if they need to modify a global variable, let it be done in the main thread.

So

```
def faker_function(params):
    items = []
    for _ in range(0, num_rows - 1):
        items.append(getattr(params[1], params[2])(**params[3]))
    return params[0], items
```

and then in your main function:

```
   data_frame = {}
   with Pool(10) as p:
       for key, result in p.map(faker_function, items):
            data_frame[key] = result;
```

No need for a data manager.

Comment: I am convinced with 2, but I don't agree 1 - generating 1m records for a single column is time consuming. `pyint` is the simplest generator and for 1m items it takes 5 seconds for each operation. When you have hundreds of columns, it does affect the performance.

Comment: "You can get it to work, but it's extremely slow and error prone.", I guess. Though I do wonder what is the use case for the manager then. I know that concurrent datas tructures and stuff are using locks and so on, and I thought the manager is something like that too.

Comment: 1) If each item takes 5s, then by all means use threads.  If each item takes 5ms, then using threads is probably not going to win you anything.   2) Managers work by having one thread "own" the object, and the other threads get a proxy that get get sent to the owning thread.  For some complex operations, this makes sense.  In this case, it doesn't.

Comment: 2) I guess in my case it won't make a difference because I will write a list of million records at once into the dictionary. I guess if I wrote it incrementally, it would make sense to use a manager.